# Why Brick and Mortar Merchants should support Cryptocurrency

Tags: cryptocurrency-comparison

An observation rather than a question:

I live near Chicago and the banks, restaurants, and other stores that sell goods that are getting robbed are on the rise.

If the stores moved to cryptocurrency, they wouldn't get robbed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only that but if merchants solely accepted payments in crypto, another plus is that PCI-DSS compliance cost associated with accepting credit card payments on a commerce server checkout cart goes to zero. A commerce server has absolutely no need to store any private keys online. The same applies to a brick and mortar checkout station.